# How to unset WooCommerce custom delivery checkout fields programmatically?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout, custom-fields

I am unsetting some checkout fields in Woocommerce via code and I am a little stumped on how to unset some custom checkout fields *(not default Woocommerce checkout fields)*. Note that I am using [Custom WooCommerce Checkout Fields Editor](https://wordpress.org/plugins/add-fields-to-checkout-page-woocommerce/) and [Delivery & Pickup Date Time for WooCommerce](https://wordpress.org/plugins/woo-delivery/) third party plugins.

Below is the code I am writing that unsets some of the woocommerce related fields *(billing, shipping and order)*:

```
 /**
 Remove following checkout fields
 **/
function wc_remove_checkout_fields( $fields ) {

    // Billing fields
    unset( $fields['billing']['billing_company'] );
    unset( $fields['billing']['billing_state'] );

    // Shipping fields
    unset( $fields['shipping']['shipping_company'] );
    unset( $fields['shipping']['shipping_state'] );
    unset( $fields['shipping']['shipping_country'] );

    // Order fields
    unset( $fields['order']['order_comments'] );

    return $fields;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'wc_remove_checkout_fields' );
```

HTML of delivery data field:

```
<input type="text" class="input-text flatpickr-input active" name="coderockz_woo_delivery_date_field" id="coderockz_woo_delivery_date_datepicker" placeholder="Delivery Date" value="" data-selectable_dates="365" data-disable_week_days="[]" data-date_format="F j, Y" data-disable_dates="[]" data-week_starts_from="0" data-default_date="1" readonly="readonly">
```

But how do I unset some custom checkout fields added via a third party plugin?

**••• Edit •••**

```
$hide_pickup_date_time = array('coderockz_woo_delivery_delivery_date_field');

    foreach($hide_pickup_date_time as $pickup_date_time ) {
        if ($chosen_shipping_pickup == $shipping_method_pickup) {
            $fields_pickup['order'][$pickup_date_time]['required'] = false;
        }
    }
```

[image]

Plugin screenshot

[image]
[image]

Comment: They're set through a UI found within this plugin: https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/add-fields-to-checkout-page-woocommerce/

Comment: I think that's the issue, it's the key field I am not sure how it's set

Comment: I will provide screenshot :)

Comment: I have added the screenshot. The field in question is hidden as it's local pickup and that's why I need to the field to be unset as it shows me validation message. Anyway all pickup and delivery fields are displayed above the billing section

Comment: Oh, give me a min,,

Comment: Screenshot has been added

Comment: What a waste of time: in the provided settings screenshots, the plugin you are using is not Custom WooCommerce Checkout Fields Editor as you told, but Delivery & Pickup Date Time for WooCommerce plugin… Next time try to add all required useful details in your question as nobody can guess things by magic.

Comment: Oh sorry I didn't realise i accidentally put the first like checkout field editor in my question. Yeah it was suppose to be just the delivery date and time plugin I was using but my question was on the basis oh how to unset a custom field in woocommerce checkout. Maybe I put too much information in there but I did include the useful data (the code snippet). Your answer in the comment to set up my own fields seems like a good answer and it's something I am looking into, thank you for that :)